# How to add custom library to docker image

Tags: c++, docker, qt, continuous-integration

There is remote server with gitlab runner and docker. I need to build c++/qt project on it, but i should use custom qt libraries(they built with deprecated webkit). I have them on local pc. How can i create docker image with this specific libraries? Is it ok to use `COPY` command for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly use COPY from your local machine.

However, I would make sure that the custom qt libraries are available online on GitHub or so, so that the docker image can be built correctly from anywhere without having to set up every local machine where the docker image is meant to be created.

This way, you can just clone the repository and the respective branch instead of COPY in your docker file.